# Showing a language is context-free with closures

Tags: context-free-grammar

Let $L_1$ a regular language and $L_2$ a context-free one.

I need to show that
$$L = \{w \mid w = x_1y_1x_2y_2\dots x_ny_n \mbox{ where }  x_1x_2\dots x_n \in L_1 \mbox{ and } y_1y_2\dots y_n \in L_2\}$$ is context-free (or not) ($x_i$ and $y_i$ are letters under the alphabet $\{a, b\}$)

As far as I know, if $L_1$ and $L_2$ were both regular, this language would also be regular, so my guess is that this one is context-free. I need to prove this properly using only closures under homomorphisms and under intersection of a regular lang. with a context-free lang.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully your are also allowed to use closure under inverse homomorphisms (for both regular and context-free languages)?

As this is homework, I will first give a hint only. When you need more explicit help let us know.

Let us fix the alphabets: $L_i\subseteq \Sigma_i^*$, for $i=1,2$.

The operation (sometimes called *fair shuffle*) alternates letters from both languages. It is a first step to "combine" both languages by using a "parallel alphabet" $\Sigma_1\times \Sigma_2$, intersection and inverse morphism. This intermediate alphabet has pairs of letters, but is an alphabet as it is of finite cardinality.

E.g., $\{a,b\}\times \{0,1,2\} = \{ (a,0), (b,0), (a,1), (b,1), (a,2), (b,2)  \}$.
For $abba\in L_1$ and $1120 \in L_2$ we code both strings as $(a,1)(b,1)(b,2)(a,0)$.

Comment: Judging by the OP’s comments to my answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266440/is-this-language-context-free-a-tricky-one/266441#comment583308_266441), the OP either is not allowed to use closure under inverse homomorphisms or would very much prefer not to do so.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes, you are right: that is why I asked. It seems one definitely needs some nondeterminism on how to code and combine, and I can do that only with inverse morphisms.

Comment: Or directly with pushdown automata.

Comment: @HendrikJan Thanks alot for the hint! As Mr. Brian said, I can't use (and don't know how to use) inverse homomorphisms, only homomorphisms. Any idea for that?

Comment: Sorry, no, I only know solutions that use inverse morphisms. (Or techniques that directly use grammars, automata...)

Comment: @HendrikJan can you please post the full solution using inverse homomorphism? I would like to better understand this kind of closure. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

On request I will make the answer more explicit. The best way, I now realize, is to use another approach. Hence my new answer.

Consider the more general operation of *shuffle*. Starting with two strings we interleave the letters from both strings, but not necessarily fair and alternating. The result is a set of words. So with $w_1 = ababab$ and $w_2 = aaabbb$ we get for example $aabaaabbabbb$ (fair), $abababaaabbb$ (first complete $w_1$) or $aaabaabbabbb$ (more randomly?) and many other strings. How do we test whether a string is in the shuffle? By marking the letters:
$a_1a_2b_1a_2a_1a_2b_1b_2a_1b_2b_1b_2$, $a_1b_1a_1b_1a_1b_1a_2a_2a_2b_2b_2b_2$, or $a_2a_1a_2b_1a_1a_2b_2b_1a_1b_2b_2b_1$. If the projections to $1$-letters and $2$-letters form $w_1$ and $w_2$ we have done ok.

The projections can be formalized as morphisms. Let $\Sigma_i=\{a_i,b_i\}$ and $\pi_1:(\Sigma_1\cup\Sigma_2)^* \to \Sigma^*$ is the morphism that maps $a_1,b_1$ to $a,b$ and 
$a_2,b_2$ both to $\epsilon$. Similarly $\pi_2$ deletes $a_1,b_1$ and maps $a_2,b_2$ to $a,b$. If $w\in(\Sigma_1\cup\Sigma_2)^*$ it is a *marked shuffle* of $w_1$ and $w_2$ if $\pi_1(w) = w_1$ and $\pi_2(w) = w_2$.

This can also be done with languages, shuffling all strings of them. E.g., $L_1 = (ab)^*$ and $L_2 = \{ a^nb^n \mid n\ge 0\}$ fit the string example above. We recognize a marked shuffle $w$ of strings in $L_1$ and $L_2$ by applying morphisms $\pi_i(w) \in L_i$, $i=1,2$. In other words, by definition of inverse operation, $w\in \pi_i^{-1}(L_i)$, $i=1,2$.
Thus the set of all marked shuffles equals $\pi_1^{-1}(L_1) \cap \pi_2^{-1}(L_2)$.

How do we additionally check for marked *fair* shuffles: by allowing only shuffles where the two alphabets alternate:  $(\Sigma_1\Sigma_2)^* \cap \pi_1^{-1}(L_1) \cap \pi_2^{-1}(L_2)$.

Finally we retrieve the shuflles, without the markings, by applying the morphism $h:(\Sigma_1\cup\Sigma_2)^* \to \Sigma^*$ that maps $a_i,b_i$ to $a,b$, $i=1,2$.

Thus $L = h(\,(\Sigma_1\Sigma_2)^* \cap \pi_1^{-1}(L_1) \cap \pi_2^{-1}(L_2)\,)$.

If $L_i$ is regular/context-free, then so is $\pi_1^{-1}(L_i)$. If (at most) one of them is context-free, then the result is context-free. If both are regular, then so is the resulting fair shuffle.